# Access the arrow style used in \vec command that looks different from \rightarrow

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to get the exact same arrow used in the \vec command. The \rightarrow command gives me an arrow that looks different. Looks like it's a different font. Anybody has any idea what's the secret behind the difference?

I know the the \vec give an italic or slanted font but that's not the entire explanation :)

Thanks for any insight!

[image: Arrow difference between \vec and \rightarrow]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Which fonts are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't set any specific font and this is the standard computer modern font, I think. I used LaTeXiT to produce the screenshot of my post and here is the header : \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is math accent 17E. I found the character code with `\xshowcmd` from the `xpatch` package. You can print the character by itself with `\mathchar"`, however it will be in the accent position. To use it standalone you can lower and scale it. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%\xshowcmd\vec
$\vec{v} \rightarrow \mathchar"17E$\raisebox{-6pt}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\mathchar"17E$}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A pinpoint answer! :D